# dropwizard unit test throwing UniformInterfaceException

Tags: java, rest, junit, jersey, dropwizard

I know this question must have been asked a thousand times before, but none of the answers at Stackoverflow work for me. I am trying to create a unit test for a restful api which uses basic authentication. Here is the code for API:

```
@GET
@Timed
@Path("/getAuthPerson/{id}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Person getAuthPerson(@PathParam("id")int id, @Auth Person user) {

    /* use HTTP header:
    Authorization : Basic dGVzdDpzZWNyZXQ=

    For negative test case, use
    Authorization : Basic dGVzdDoxMjM=
     */

    if(user.getName().isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }

    Person p = new Person();
    p.setName("Test");
    p.setId(0);
    p.setAge(10);

    return p;
}
```

This API works when I call RESTful client of browser, my IDE or from Fiddler i.e. I am correctly getting 401 when I don't provide auth header/incorrect header and am able to get back the resource when I provide correct header. However, the unit test api refuses to work, here is the code for unit-test:

```
public class PersonResourceTest {
private static final PersonDao personDao = mock(PersonDao.class);

@ClassRule
public static final ResourceTestRule resources = ResourceTestRule.builder()
        .addResource(new PersonResource(personDao))
        .build();

private static Person getDummyPerson() {
    Person person = new Person();
    person.setName("John Doe");
    person.setBirthDateTime(new DateTime("2012-11-21T13:01:33.568Z"));
    person.setAge(10);
    return person;
}

private final Person person = getDummyPerson();

@Before
public void setup() {
    when(personDao.getPerson(eq(123))).thenReturn(person);
    // we have to reset the mock after each test because of the
    // @ClassRule, or use a @Rule as mentioned below.
    reset(personDao);
}

@Test
public void authenticatedTestGetPositive() {
    PersonDao testDao = mock(PersonDaoMongoImpl.class);
    testDao.createPerson(person);

    WebResource.Builder builder = resources.client().resource("/persons/getAuthPerson/123").getRequestBuilder();
    builder.header("Authorization", "Basic dGVzdDpzZWNyZXQ=");
    //builder.header("Authorization", "Basic dGVzdDoxMjM=");
    builder.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    Person p = builder.get(Person.class);
    assertThat(p).isEqualTo(person);
    verify(testDao).getPerson(123);
}
```

}

The unit test which does not involve authentication works perfectly, however this authentication unit test gives this error:

```
    ERROR [2014-08-10 14:48:58,108] com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest: A message body reader for Java class com.rms.pilotapi.core.Person, and Java type class com.rms.pilotapi.core.Person, and MIME media type application/octet-stream was not found.
The registered message body readers compatible with the MIME media type are:
    */* ->
      com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider
      com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider
      com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
      --snipped---
```

Comment: I solved this by adding `addProvider(new BasicAuthProvider<>(new BasicAuthenticator(), "TestAuthenticator"))` to `@ClassRule` line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to register your `PersonAuthenticator` (or whichever name you used for your Authenticator) in the JUnit testrule (`@ClassRule`).

The problem is that Jersey tries to deserialize your parameter `@Auth Person user`, which should be handled by your authenticator.

Comment: Hey @phXql thank you for your reply, one more (very stupid) question, how do I register the authenticator in `@ClassRule`, I am very new to this and can't figure it out.

Comment: I am marking this as an answer because I noticed that the new Jersey framework (2.0+) does have a `register()` method for `Client`. However, dropwizard still uses v1.8 which does not have this method. Can you please suggest something for 1.8?0

Comment: On your ResourceTestRule builder call `.addProvider(new BasicAuthProvider<User>(new PocAuthenticator(), "Auth-Provider for tests"))`.

See this project on github for example: https://github.com/phxql/dropwizard-itest-authentication